# isset in php not working in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, variables, angularjs-routing, isset

I am new to angularjs and I am having issue with using `isset` in **php**. I am developing a website using angularjs-1. I want to get the value of the parameter in the url but I can't do it. Here's my code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider
    .when('admin/dashboard/gallery/folder'{
          templateUrl: '_pages/gallery-folder',
          controller: 'gfCTRL',
          resolve: {
                delay: function($q, $timeout){
                     var delay = $q.defer();
                     $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
                     return delay.promise;
                  }
          }
     });
});

app.controller('gfCTRL', function($scope, $rootScope){
     $rootScope.statechange = true;
});
```

And in my HTML:

```
<a href="admin/dashboard/gallery/folder?name=sample&lbl=2">Open</a>
```

And in my PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['lbl'])){
    echo $_GET['lbl'];
}else{
    echo "None";
}
```

For now, it only gives me the result of `none`. Why?

Comment: Have you tried `$_POST['lbl']`?

Comment: Yes, but still not working :(

Comment: Likely your "route" is failing on the PHP's side. Echo `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: It only gives me the actual page `/cvsrrc/_pages/gallery-folder`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check `$_GET['lbl'];` as `var_dump($_GET['lbl']);`
i would also make your check also check for nothing.
ex:
`if(isset($_GET['lbl']) && $_GET['lbl'] !== "") // This also makes sure something is entered. Because any one can delete part of the $lbl=2`

i would first check to see if `$_GET` is getting `lbl` with var_dump if not it might be spelling or something else. Always make a check to test your work in building.

Comment: `undefined index: lbl` -> `NULL`

Comment: your link is being altered then your `<a>` tag is altered.

Comment: What do you mean sir? @DarkSideKillaz

Comment: the link `<a href="admin/dashboard/gallery/folder?name=sample&lbl=2">Open</a>` is not going to gallery/folder?name=.... add your variables to  `templateUrl: '_pages/gallery-folder',` add `?name=sample&lbl=2` then check your `var_dump($_GET['lbl']);`

Comment: It will go to that link. But not getting the `parameters` in the url

Comment: if that fixes it then you will need to get the url variables in your `templateUrl: '_pages/gallery-folder'`